# How to color the output stream of std::cout, but not of std::cerr and std::clog?

Tags: c++, c++17, output, outputstream, ansi-escape

I am dealing with the following problem: I am on Ubuntu and if I color all the stream in red, for example with the following command:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "\033[31m" << "From now on the stream is red!";
```

what happens is that not only the `std::cout` object, but also `std::cerr` and `std::clog` objects will display red strings from now on.

I was wondering if is there a way to color only `std::cout` output and let `std::cerr` and `std::clog` outputs unchanged, in a way to be able to do:

```
#include <iostream>

std::cout << "\033[31m" << "From now on the std::cout stream is red!"; // red stream
std::cerr << "This stream is NOT red"; // normal stream (not colored)
std::clog << "This stream is NOT red"; // normal stream (not colored)
```

What I need is a "setting" (function, class etc...) able to fix this requirement at the beginning of the program and let it unchanged until the end.

How can I do this?

Comment: `std::cout << "\033[31m" << "From now on the stream is red!" << "\033[0m";`

Comment: You are not colouring *streams*. Streams have no colour. You are colouring your *terminal*. The terminal is a device, not a stream. There may be multiple streams associated with the same device, but the streams themselves nor any part of the C++ library you can access are not aware of the fact.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. That looks like it can be posted as an answer. Perhaps with a bit more detail, but it's useful even as is.

Comment: Yes and I would vote it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of tries I found a pretty suitable solution for this problem. I simply created a functor able to apply changes directly to the `std::ostream` object, to be used in this way:

```
functor( std::cout ) << "Modified output stream";
```

Such an implementation si a bit long and can be found [here](https://github.com/JustWhit3/osmanip/blob/main/include/manipulators/printer.hpp).